# Why binding to label's enabled property crashes the app

Tags: xamarin.ios, uilabel, mvvm-light, portable-class-library, xamarin.ios-binding

I am trying to bind a view model variable with label's enabled property but it crashes the app

```
bindings.Add(this.SetBinding(() => this.Vm.IsEnabled, () => this.lblDate.Enabled, BindingMode.TwoWay));
```

The crash is always reproducible in release mode.

[image]

Here is the [crash report](https://gist.github.com/Duraiamuthan/84a2edb1524e5dce373b7b639cfdd98d)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Enabled property of lblDate doesn't have a public setter, but being a control I am almost sure it has. I found on [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23288/set-method-not-found-for-property-name-on-device-on-simulator-works) page that one solution would be to add the [Preserve] attribute to your property in view-model